# Missing File On External Under Truecrypt

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Hi, I have a Toshiba external drive, I am not able to access information that was pass-coded. I noticed that H: is missing. I only have drives G-Z, with H missing. I get these messages  (Error) incorrect volume size, and the system cannot find path specified when I try to enter the drive.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  This has nothing to do with IE9.  What version of Windows exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you meant to say H:\ then it isn't a file it is a directory. It also means that you are missing H: (the H drive) which is the actual problem. In reality, this is how Truecrypt works. When it encrypts a drive that drive then becomes completely unreadable by your OS until you decrypt the partition again. At that point Windows will see it as a completely different drive and assign a new drive letter. As dumb as Windows is about handling this it is smart enough to remember your settings when you tell it what you really want which is all we care about.

Tip: Windows will give you all sorts of trouble with it until you decrypt it. I would suggest going to your drive management tool and hide the unreadable partition. When you actually decrypt that drive it'll be given a new drive letter anyway and this does a good job of shutting Windows up.

The solution to this is that you must actually decrypt the drive before you can begin using it. To decrypt it you must open Truecrypt and select the encrypted partition using the "Select Device" button in Truecrypt. After that you'll be able to mount the drive using the 'Mount' button (this will require authentication). As long as you remember your password and\or key file location you'll hopefully have no trouble with this. Once mounted the newly decrypted folder will open up in Explorer ready for use.